# sharepoint 2010 foundation inserting multiple new items from predetermined list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to add multiple new items to an existing SharePoint list. The new items are based on a set of item codes, that the user will put a quantity against each received, then click insert and the item with a quantity will be added to the end of the list.

I have thought about a new item form, but we are using SharePoint 2010 foundation so infopath is not available. Instead I could use a second list with the items in it, then use a workflow to add each line with a quantity into the first list, but the problem with this is the supplier would only need to be typed once, not for each line on the second list to be tidy.

Is it possible to do what I am looking at? I have no experience with SharePoint Services.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide me an example of how do you want the items to appear in the list.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to use the comments, I cannot post images, it would have all the products (30 ish) down the left hand side, the supplier, and a box for inputting quantity, only those wuth a quantity against them needs to be actioned, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to do what you want to achieve.

To deal with the Sharepoint Web Services you can use [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) lib or the popular [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).

However you'll need to have some JavaScript skills to reach your goal.
Your code could be something like (using SharepointPlus):

```
<input type="text" id="itemCode" placeholder="Item Code">
<input type="text" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
<input type="button" value="Add" id="buttonAdd">
<script>
$('#buttonAdd').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $SP().list("Your ListName for the Quantities").add({
    Title:$('#itemCode').val(),
    Quantity:$('#quantity').val()
  }, {
    error:function(items) {
      if (items.length>0) alert("There are some errors !")
    },
    success:function(items) {
      if (items.length===1) alert("Done!")
    }
  });
})
</script>
```

If the list where you want to add the new item is called "Your ListName for the Quantities" with two columns: "Title" for the item code, and "Quantity" for the quantity.